# Почему php in_array() возвращает false, хотя должно true?

Tags: php

```
$gl = array('а', 'е', 'ё', 'и', 'о', 'у', 'ы', 'э', 'ю', 'я');
  $sogl = array('б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ь', 'ч');
  $str = $_GET['str'];
  $str_array = str_split($str, 1);

  $gl_counter = 0;
  $sogl_counter = 0;

  foreach ($str_array as $current_letter) {
    if (in_array($current_letter, $gl)) {
      $gl_counter++;
    }
    if (in_array($current_letter, $sogl)) {
      $sogl_counter++;
    }
  }

echo $gl_counter;
  echo ", ";
  echo $sogl_counter;
```

В str_array у меня хранятся элементы массива, соответствующие каждой введенной букве в textarea. Затем, я хочу посчитать количество гласных и согласных букв в нем. Однако, счетчик не обновляется, потому что функция in_array всегда возвращает false. Однако же если заменить $current_letter на какую-то конкретную букву, например 'a', то тогда счетчик будет обновляться. Я пробовал вывести массив букв и он работает правильно (буквы выводятся). В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам надо использовать функцию **[mb_str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-str-split.php)** для работы с многобайтовой строкой, которой является текст на русском. А `str_split` разбивает строку вот на такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_str_split()`. Эта функция есть только в php 8 или в более ранних версиях тоже? У меня php 7.1

Comment: @hot_penguin везде есть >=7.0. Просто надо соответствующее расширение поставить (если не установлено) и включить его в php.ini. Обычно достаточно второго

Comment: эта функция работает от php 7.4. Изменил версию на 7.4 и все заработало. Спасибо!